# How to have Safari restore form data?

Tags: safari, web-browsing, web-browser, safari-extensions

I want to have Safari restore form data when restoring my session. This should be native, but Safari does not have this — yet.

[The extension Lazarus](http://getlazarus.com) looks great. But it does not work.

I have also looked at [an extension named Form Autosave](https://web.archive.org/web/20130908130730/http://canisbos.com/formsaver). But it is crappy.

I have Safari 7 on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Argh, just noticed that Lazarus isn't working since the upgrade to Mavericks.  It was truly a lifesaver (and worked quite well).

Comment: The link in the original question above… {http://canisbos.com/formsaver} …is broken.